# "The import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiDevice is never used". Which Package or Jar file I need to import for using class UiDevice

Tags: android-sdk-tools, android-uiautomator, uidevice, uiautomatorviewer

**Note:** Below Jars are imported for using UiDevice class and its properties.

1) Added Jar file "uiautomator.jar" from my latest SDK folder. By this I imported com.android.uiautomator.core.UiDevice. Here, it is displaying the error message saying as "The import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiDevice is never used".

2) Added Jar file "uiautomator-v18-2.1.2-sources.jar"(Read it from few blogs to use class UiDevice). But here it consists of only one **empty package** "android.support.test.uiautomator"

Which Package and Jar I need to add to my Eclipse for using UiDevice class and its properties?